# JPA avoid extra read call for a association object while saving the object

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have two JPA entities like below with their respective getters and setters for each field which I have ommitted in the code below.

```
1. 

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;
}

2. 
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false)
    private Post post;
}
```

While saving a comment object I have to do something like below

```
Post post = postRepository.findById(postId)
comment.setPost(post);
commentRepository.save(comment);
```

Question is how to avoid loading a Post object before saving comment. Basically I want to avoid this extra db read call but I don't want to loose the association.

```
Post post = postRepository.findById(postId);
```

One option is to use to simply use brand_id as below but I loose the association which I don't want to loose.

```
private Long post_id;
```

Comment: *I want to avoid this extra db read call* - are you sure that this is actually an extra read?  It could very well be cached.

Comment: use `getById` instead of `findById` (assuming you are using Spring Data JPA). Else use `entityManager.getReference` (which is wat `getById` is also doing).

Answer (score 3):

```
EntityManager.getReference(...)
```

That should do the trick.